# Android Studio - Firestore send email verification

Tags: java, android

Good day, I would like to ask if it is possible to send an email verification using Firestore in my android studio app.

the Firebaseauth.sendEmailVerification do not seem to work on it and I cannot find much sources about Sending email verification with the use of FireStore. If you have any references feel free to send it. Thank you!

Tried adding

```
firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification()
```

But it does not seem to work since it is FireStore?

Comment: have you enable Email settings in Auth menu?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the **getInstance()** is missing that's why you are not able to send the verification mail to the user.

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
user.sendEmailVerification();
```

Check if the email is verified or not.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();
```

Hope it works